# Create a separate list of all duplicates from original list

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

I have a list of Objects. Each of those objects has a boolean duplicate variable on them. At the end of my algorithm I want all the objects which there are more than one of (duplicates identified by a string identifier on the object) to have boolean duplicate = true. I have done it like so, but am wondering if there is a way to do this more efficiently, ideally with only one loop.

```
List<String> dupIds = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, MyObject> objMap = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();  
for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    if (objMap.containsKey(o.getId()) {
        dupIds.add(o.getId());
    } else {
        objMap.put(o.getId(), o);
    }
}

for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    if (dupIds.contains(o.getId) {
        o.setDuplicate(true);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question, but most of the ones I found aren't doing this exactly, usually just removing duplicates (I need to keep them) or only marking the copies (I need to mark the copies plus the original).

Comment: I don't get what do you want to do..:-( I don't know if I am the only one. Can you make some example? I guess you are looking for some Multimap-like stuff.

Comment: You could store MyObjects in the dupIds list then the second loop would be on dupIds only instead of the whole objectlist.

Comment: @Kent sorry, I know the wording isn't the greatest. An example: If I have obj1, obj2, and obj3, with obj1 and obj2 each having the same id, then I want the duplicate flag on each of those two objects to be set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient way, but it gets rid of the second loop :

```
Map<String, MyObject> objMap = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();  
for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    if (objMap.containsKey(o.getId()) {
        objMap.get(o.getId()).setDuplicate(true);
        o.setDuplicate(true);
    } else {
        objMap.put(o.getId(), o);
    }
}
```

When you find a duplicate in the map, you mark both the current object and the object in the map as duplicate. If an object appears more than two times, you might call `setDuplicate` on the same object multiple times, so you might want to check if the flag is already set before setting it.

Update :

Here's a solution that won't call `setDuplicate` multiple times on the same object :

```
Map<String, MyObject> objMap = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();  
for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    if (objMap.containsKey(o.getId()) {
        MyObject other = objMap.get(o.getId());
        if (other != null) {
            othet.setDuplicate(true);
            objMap.put(o.getId(), null);
        }
        o.setDuplicate(true);
    } else {
        objMap.put(o.getId(), o);
    }
}
```

- When you encounter an object the 1st time, you put it in the map.
- When you encounter an object the 2nd time, you `setDuplicate` to the current object and the object from the map, and you put a null as the value of the object's ID in the map.
- When you encounter an object the 3rd time (or more), you only `setDuplicate` to the current object.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately doesn't work for me because of a simplification I made for the sake of this question. In your example if there is more than one duplicate you are calling setDuplicate(true) on the original object more than once. That is fine here with booleans, but in my actual implementation I am not setting a boolean but rather adding a string to a list of Strings in the case of a duplicate. This didn't work for me because the original would get the multiple copies of the string in its String list.

Comment: @bhouse This can be easily solved. You can check, for example, if the String was already added before adding it.

Comment: that is true. I wonder if it is more efficient that way than with two loops. It sure seems like it would be faster to eliminate the loop like you have, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @bhouse See my new suggestion, which eliminates the multiple `setDuplicate`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably first find all duplicate keys, using two hash sets, and after that set the boolean on each of the objects.

It has the same asymptotic time complexity as your solution (and Eran's), which is `O(n)`, but I find this easier to follow (but that's just a matter of taste, of course).

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> duplicateKeys = new HashSet<>();

for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    if (keys.contains(o.getId())
        duplicateKeys.add(o.getId());
    keys.add(o.getId());
}

for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    o.setDuplicate(duplicateKeys.contains(o.getId()));
}
```

Comment: Yeah this may be easier. It's the same thing really except Set is used instead of List/Map, but your right I think its a bit cleaner. I'm not too familiar with Big O notation, but wouldn't this be something like O(2n) whereas Eran's would be O(n) due to the extra loop?